# Cannot load module with PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, pythonpath

I have a project called `library` and in it I have 3 folders - `user`, `book` and `main`. There is a `user_utility.py` in `user`. So let's say the project folder is:

```
/User/me/Projects/library/user/user_utility.py
/User/me/Projects/library/book/book_utility.py
/User/me/Projects/library/main/main.py
```

Now, in `/User/me/Projects/library/main/main.py` I would like to write the import statement as:

```
from user.user_utility import UserUtility
```

What is the `$PYTHONPATH` variable that allows me to do so? I tried

```
EXPORT PYTHONPATH="/User/me/Projects/library
```

but it does not work and it threw

```
No module named user.user_utility
```

Comment: To be an importable module, the directory must also contain a file named `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messing with `PYTHONPATH` really is the wrong approach to go forward here. Instead, turn your `user` and `book` folders into proper modules/submodules. For doing so, you need to add `__init__.py` -files to (both of) them, looking like this for example:

```
from user_utility import some_routine
```

In your example, this would be `/User/me/Projects/library/user/__init__.py`. Now you can import this routine from your `main.py`-file as follows:

```
from user import some_routine
```

For full reference, have a look at [the python documentation, modules tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: i'll take your answer. what i need to do is to only point to the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you call **main.py**  directly from the command line, you can set the environment variable at the beginning of the line:

```
 PYTHONPATH=/User/me/Projects/Library python main.py
```

Otherwise, you should be able to set that module lookup path with:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/User/me/Projects/Library
```

To verify, you can see your environment variables with:

```
env
```

Also, make sure to put the **__init__.py** inside the user folder.